# Can we use sounddevice library in Python to play an audio file (.wav or .mp3) on a virtual cable instead of pygame library in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, virtualization, python3

Can I work with Virtual Cables in Ubuntu using sounddevice library of Python? I am trying to play an audio file on a Virtual Cable. I have done this using pygame library. Now, I need to do it using sounddevice library. Is there a way?

Comment: What version of ub*a*ntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS